# Installation failed - Visual Studio Code on Windows Vista

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: I am on Windows Vista and can not install it]
To file a bug report I found only how to do it from the app;)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code has been tested on the following platforms.

- Ubuntu Desktop 14.04
- OS X Yosemite
- Windows 8.0, 8.1 and 10 (x86 and x64)

Official info in the website (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Google knows everything, and I found what's going on here: [Microsoft desktop library docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317326(v=vs.85).aspx).

This method `RegisterTouchWindow` is supported from Windows 8. **Kind of expected.**

Visual Studio Code download page states support for Vista;) I didn't use Microsoft Products (except OS) for some time, though shall be surprised:)